# When retrieving data to edit the select does not show the saved data by default

Tags: python, django, forms, select, crud

I'm doing a crud, one of the model's fields is a foreign key to another model and when I open a record saved in the form to edit instead of the select showing the data saved by default it shows empty. Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Imovel(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey("Cliente", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from imoveis.models import Imovel, Cliente


class FormImovel(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Imovel

        fields = [
            'numero',
            'cliente',
        ]


class FormCliente(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cliente

        fields = [
            'nome',
            'email',
        ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from imoveis.forms import FormCliente, FormImovel
from imoveis.models import Imovel, Cliente


def imoveis(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormImovel(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'imoveis.html')


def clientes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormCliente(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'clientes.html')


def insere_imovel(request):
    form = FormImovel()
    return render(request, 'imovel_form.html', {'form': form})


def edita_imovel(request, imovel_id):
    imovel = get_object_or_404(Imovel, pk=imovel_id)
    form = FormImovel(imovel.__dict__)
    return render(request, 'imovel_form.html',
                  {'form': form, 'imovel_id': imovel_id})


def insere_cliente(request):
    form = FormCliente()
    return render(request, 'cliente_form.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from imoveis.views import clientes, imoveis, insere_imovel, edita_imovel, insere_cliente 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('clientes/', clientes, name='clientes'),
    path('imoveis/', imoveis, name='imoveis'),
    path('insere_cliente/', insere_cliente, name='insere_cliente'),
    path('insere_imovel/', insere_imovel, name='insere_imovel'),
    path('edita_imovel/<int:imovel_id>', edita_imovel, name='edita_imovel'),
]
```

templates/imovel_form.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'imoveis' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_table }}
<button type="submit">salvar</button>
</form>
```

I need the select generated by the foreign key when opening the record for editing to show me the data saved in that field by default.
on open to edit i have this:
[i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnEyB.png)

but i need this:
[i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrX3K.png)

Comment: try ```POST``` instead of ```post``` in form.